# Fetch Category Image from collection object without loading category object

Tags: magento2, category, performance

I am trying to get the category image from the below code

```
      $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name','image')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_popular', array('eq' => 1))
               ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',array('eq' => 1))
               ->addAttributeToSort('category_sort_no', 'ASC')
               ->setPageSize(12)
               ->load();
```

and i am looping through these but i am not getting category image.I can get category id from the collection and load the category object and get the image.But it is affecting the performance like below:

```
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
$imgUrl = $category->getImageUrl();
```

Is there any way we can fetch the category image from the collection object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try the steps descriibe  blow

step 1)
In template phtml file

```
<?php foreach ($collection as $category):
    $categoryImageUrl = $block->getThumbnailUrl($category->getThumbnail());
 ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $categoryImageUrl;?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName() ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName() ?>" />
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Step 2)
In php block class  file:

```
......................
......................
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
 Context $context, 
 StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        ......................
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

public function getThumbnailUrl($imageName){
        $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ) . 'catalog/category/' . $imageName;
        return $url;
    }
......................
......................
```

Comment: I am trying to get image but not thumbnail image